# Why I got errors in a brand new webapp-javaee7 project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I created a project in Eclipse Keppler for Java EE Developers by selecting file->new->maven project-> webapp-javaee7 archetype.
But before writing a single line of code I got errors:

> Resource '/test/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml' does not exist.

and:

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.6:copy (execution: default, phase: validate)   pom.xml /test   line 53 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

[image]

Why web.xml is not created?
Why Plugin execution is not covered by lifecycle configuration?

I have a clean installation of Eclipse and the latest M2Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to ORACLE docs about `web.xml deployment descriptor`, `web.xml` is no longer a requirement, you can use Java EE annotations instead:

From [web.xml Deployment Descriptor Elements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/webapp/web_xml.html):

> With Java EE annotations, the standard web.xml deployment descriptor
>   is optional. According to the Servlet 2.5 specification, annotations
>   can be defined on certain web components, such as servlets, filters,
>   listeners, and tag handlers. The annotations are used to declare
>   dependencies on external resources. See WebLogic Annotation for Web
>   Components.

So, you can safely ignore the

> Resource '/test/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml' does not exist

error.

However you can create the `web.xml` file by right clicking on the project and selecting `Java EE Tools` -> `Generate Deployment Descriptor Stub`

To fix the

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration

error, you need to install `m2e connector for maven-dependency-plugin`.

Answer (score 0):

The message is pretty clear.

```
Resource '/test/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml' does not exist.
```

you have to create the web.xml file in the directory: `test/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/`

It will not automaticaly created.

Comment: Why is not created automatically If it is needed for a brand new project? I think an archetype should include at least the bare minimum to build without errors